# Access Global .resx file in ASP.Net View Page

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources

I am currently building in Version 3.5 of the .Net framework and I have a resource (.resx) file that I am trying to access in a web application.  I have exposed the .resx properties as public access modifiers and am able to access these properties in the controller files or other .cs files in the web app.  My question is this: Is it possible to access the name/value pairs within my view page?  I'd like to do something like this...

```
text="<%$ Resources: Namespace.ResourceFileName, NAME %>"
```

or some other similar method in the view page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```cs
<%= Resources.<ResourceName>.<Property> %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Expose the resource property you want to consume in the page as a protected page property.  Then you can just do use "this.ResourceName"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET 2.0 or higher, after you compile with the resource file, you can reference it through the Resources namespace:

```
text = Resources.YourResourceFilename.YourProperty;
```

You even get Intellisense on the filenames and properties.